# GraphQL API Lost Connection

Tags: ruby, docker-compose, graphql

I have a machine with a [docker-graphql/server](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql) that runs a Graphql API.

I was normally connecting to that machine with HTTP requests trough:

```rb
uri = URI.parse("http://#{ENV['IP_CARDANO_GRAPHQL_API_SERVER']}:3100/")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Accept"] = "application/json"
request["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
request["Dnt"] = "1"
request["Origin"] = "http://#{ENV['IP_CARDANO_GRAPHQL_API_SERVER']}:3100"

obj = {"query": query}

request.body = JSON.dump(obj)

req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    read_timeout: 5
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
end
# puts response.code
return JSON.parse(response.body)['data']
```

but suddenly it stopped working end up with this problem:

```
Caused by:
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:217:in `rbuf_fill'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1509:in `block in transport_request'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1506:in `catch'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1506:in `transport_request'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1479:in `request'
/Users/sergio/Documents/github/learn/front-end/delegations-explorer/Rakefile:218:in `block in query_graphql'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:920:in `start'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:605:in `start'
/Users/sergio/Documents/github/learn/front-end/delegations-explorer/Rakefile:217:in `query_graphql'
/Users/sergio/Documents/github/learn/front-end/delegations-explorer/Rakefile:130:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/sergio/Documents/github/learn/front-end/delegations-explorer/Rakefile:116:in `each'
/Users/sergio/Documents/github/learn/front-end/delegations-explorer/Rakefile:116:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => getRewards
```

The playgroung works just fine from the local machine where the ruby script is running from.

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward: debug your network connection to the endpoint.

Comment: for some reason it seems more of a client problem as when I try to access the playground from my phone it does work... any ideas? thanks!

Comment: just found out that the playground actually works if I use Chrome rather than Brave. But the problem persists with the Ruby script as in the code above. Why suddenly I get `Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>` ?